# How to choose the saving directory when merging csv file with cmd

Tags: cmd

I am completely new to this prompt window command

I know that
`copy *.csv filename.csv`
will merge all the CSV files in the folder and save it in the same folder with all the CSV files. I want to separate the input and output folder. Wonder if there is a way to choose the desired directory instead of saving it in the same folder.

Thanks

Comment: You can specify both the source and the destination folder (if required). Use quotes to make it safe for (possible) spaces: `copy "c:\source folder\*.csv" "d:\destination folder\filename.csv"`

Comment: @Stephan Thanks! this is exactly what i wanted. Much appreciated